# Redirect to non-www-url domain with MVC4 / IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

First of all, I just spent a few hours on Stackoverflow reading similar questions but no answer seems to work for me.

I have an MVC4 application which has an SEO issue : the non-www is not redirected to www. I have installed the Rewrite module on the server (IIS7.5) and on my local environment (VS2010).
I tried many ways but none seems to work...

Ideally, I would prefer to have the rewrite rule in my MVC4 solution and avoid doing server side configuration as it is more convenient when deploying to new servers.

I tried to put the following code block in my web.config :

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!-- code added for SEO non-www to www redirect -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove WWW prefix" >
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}"
              redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <!-- SEO code -->
  </system.webServer>
```

I then published the solution (with the right domain name) but nothing changes. When trying to access http://domain.com, I just get a 404 not found error.

I tried several code block for this part but it just never work. I also tried to configure this on the server, which didn't work as well. The best solution would be to have this rewrite in my web.config so the rules are applied whenever I publish to a new web server.

Does anyone sees something wrong with this ? My web.config is in my MVC4 application and published via the Publish menu we get when right-clicking the solution in VS2010.

Thank you very much in advance for your replies.

I also tried this block for the rule but it doesn't change anything..

```
  <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```